# Winform five Serial ports for loop to send message

Tags: .net, winforms, serial-port, c++-cli

I am new in C++/CLI winform serial port, and I need to control five Arduinos in the same time. Now I can open them and send messages one by one.

```
this->_serialPort1->WriteLine(szCommand);
this->_serialPort2->WriteLine(szCommand‌​); 
this->_serialPort3->WriteLine(szCommand);
```

But it is so cumbersome. So I want to know is there any way to control them by for loop or something else, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i< 3; i++) 
{ 
    "_serialport" + System::Convert::ToString(i+1)->WriteLine(szCommand); 
}
```

I can only find controls could realize what I want, but serial port doesn't belong to controls...

```
for (int i = 0; i< 3; i++)
{    
    ((System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox ^)Controls->Find("CheckBox"
        + System::Convert::ToString(i+1), true)[0])->Checked = false;
}
```

Comment: So you want to be able to select multiple Arduinos via checkboxes and send a message to them?

Comment: No, I have _serialport1, _serialport2, _serialport3 . Now my programming is: this->_serialPort1->WriteLine(szCommand);this->_serialPort2->WriteLine(szCommand); this->_serialPort3->WriteLine(szCommand); But I want to change it to a for loop to send messages like this:for (int i = 0; i< 3; i++)

{    
"_serialport" + System::Convert::ToString(i+1)->WriteLine(szCommand);
}

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm going to assume that `this->_serialPort1` is of type [`SerialPort^`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx?cs-lang=cpp).

You've obviously declared some local storage for these serial ports. Just make it an container of some sort, and iterate. I'll use [`System::Collections::Generic::List`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx?cs-lang=cpp).

```
List<SerialPort^>^ serialPorts = gcnew List<SerialPort^>();
serialPorts->Add(gcnew SerialPort("COM1"));
serialPorts->Add(gcnew SerialPort("COM2"));
serialPorts->Add(gcnew SerialPort("COM3"));
serialPorts->Add(gcnew SerialPort("COM4"));
serialPorts->Add(gcnew SerialPort("COM5"));

for each(SerialPort^ port in serialPorts)
{
    port->WriteLine(szCommand);
}
```